# 403 Forbidden error google plus python

Tags: python, oauth, google-plus

There are my codes:

```
import pprint
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write']

REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

CLIENT_ID = "my client id"
CLIENT_SECRET = "my client secret"
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                           client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                           scope=SCOPES,
                           redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

print 'Please paste this URL in your browser to authenticate this program.'
print auth_uri
code = raw_input('Enter the code it gives you here: ')

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('plusDomains', 'v1', http=http)

user_id = 'me'

print('Insert activity')
result = service.activities().insert(
    userId = user_id,
    body = {
        'object' : {
            'originalContent' : 'Happy Monday! #caseofthemondays'
        },
        'access' : {
            'items' : [{
                'type' : 'domain'
            }],
            'domainRestricted': True
        }
    }).execute()
print('result = %s' % pprint.pformat(result))
```

and there are my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/karl/workspace/googleplus/google_plus/google_plus_pic.py", line 44, in <module>
        'domainRestricted': False
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
        return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 680, in execute
        raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities?alt=json returned "Forbidden">
```

I have read a lot of information,but I don't know how to solve the problem.
Where is the bug?

Comment: Just to make sure, the Google Account you are authorizing is a Google Apps account right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the Google+ Domains API, you need to make sure that the Domain for the user you are acting on behalf of has been set up with the right permissions for your app.  These instructions are under the "Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account" section of Step 1 of the [quick-start guide](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/python).

Specifically, you need to associate your app's Client ID with the scopes your app will use in the control panel for the domain.  The domain administrator is the only person who can do this--so if you are working with another domain, be sure you get in contact with that person.  Also, the scopes listed in the control panel must match EXACTLY with the scopes you request in your app.